# How to call methods on arrays within an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, call

I've created an ArrayList called `groupOfPeople` by having a constructor that takes their name and ages. This was added to the ArrayList like this:

```
groupOfPeople.add(new Person(23,"Tom"));
```

Now I want to make that person call a `sleep()` method that is stored within another class. I've called it like this:

```
SleepClass callSleepClassr = new SleepClass();
```

Now I want to call the first person in the ArrayList and make them sleep so adding `.callSleepClass.sleep()` to them. The thing is, I don't know how to refer to that first array.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: iterate and call on each element OR use java8 forEach

Comment: `for (Person x : people) {
         x.callshower.shower();
    }` doesn't work, how would I make x do this?

Answer (score 1):

By using Java8 streams, you can include the check for empty list as well,

```
groupOfPeople.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(SleepClass::sleep);
```

The `sleep` method should take a `Person` parameter then.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function on each element on the list by doing:

```
for (Person  p : groupOfPeople) {
    p.callSleepClass.sleep();               
}
```

If you want to do it for the first element in the list, you can use:

```
if(groupOfPeople.size()>1)
    groupOfPeople.get(0).callSleepClass.sleep();
```

Comment: this is not correct, op defined ***groupOfPeople*** as an ArrayList, not an Array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the first element in the list to sleep then get the element at index 0 in the list and invoke the method:

```
if(!groupOfPeople.isEmpty()){
    groupOfPeople.get(0).callSleepClass.sleep();
}
```